Hyperreal valued integrals
Consider a set of real numbers $S=\{c_{\vec{x}}\}_{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3}$. That is a number for every point in 3d space. Consider the product:
$$X=\prod_{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3}c_{\vec{x}}$$
In many cases such a product will be infinite. My question is do products of this form fall under the category of the hyperreal numbers, or are divergent products over $|\mathbb{R}^3|$ many numbers "too large infinities" for this space?
On a similar note, can integrals of the form:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{x\in\mathbb{R}^3}d\varphi(x)\psi[\varphi]$$
be defined rigorously within the context of hyperreal numbers? The multidimensional integral above is over an $|\mathbb{R}^3|$ - dimensional domain.
Asking because of a statistical field theory (physics) proof I am fiddling with.

No, these $X$ not "hyperreal numbers".

@GEdgar What class of numbers could $X$ categorized under?

How is this product defined? Maybe you should start by answering this when $x$ ranges just over all of $\Bbb R$.

On merely the basis of cardinality, it would appear that hyperreals, which are simply $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ modulo a nonprincipal ultrafilter, cannot encode information from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.
I think surreal numbers would be more appropriate for this sort of investigation. (edit: but keep in mind I'm not specialized in this area of math)
